# How can i input string data in object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to input text to innerState.feedType. but when i tried
it says  Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
How can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
     const [innerState, setInnerState] = useState<any>({
       feedType: 'bbong', 
        })


     const onChangeEtcfeedtype = useCallback((text) => {
          setInnerState( innerState['feedType'] = text)
       },[]);

        <TextInput
            placeholder="input."
            value={innerState.feedType}
            onChangeText={onChangeEtcfeedtype}
          />
```

Comment: can you also share the part you used `toString` please?

Comment: @frankie303 example ("hi")

Answer (score 1):

You need to add null-safety(?) operator, because state creates after render components. Also need to return new link on object for re-render component.

```
 const [innerState, setInnerState] = useState<any>({
   feedType: 'bbong', 
    })


 const onChangeEtcfeedtype = (text) => {
      setInnerState({...innerState, innerState.feedType: text});
   };

    <TextInput
        placeholder="input."
        value={innerState?.feedType}
        onChangeText={onChangeEtcfeedtype}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you **should** write it.
About the error. It look like its not come from this part. It come from your `<TextInput />` component and possiblely caused because what you doing with onChange `event`.

```js
const [innerState, setInnerState] = useState<any>({
       feedType: 'bbong', 
     })


     const onChangeEtcfeedtype = useCallback((text) => {
          setInnerState({feedType: text})
       },[]);

        <TextInput
            placeholder="input."
            value={innerState.feedType}
            onChangeText={onChangeEtcfeedtype}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `innerState['feedType'] = text` you are changing the state directly and then store it using the updater function, you should not change it directly.

You have *innerState* which is object and it contains feedType property. So, update a state you have to pass the object with the same key with new value.

***Correct Way:***

```
setInnerState({feedType: text})
```